# jquery appendTo removes javascript script tags

Tags: jquery, append

```
var testdiv = '<div id="hello"><p>hiii</p>
               <script type="text/javascript">some javascript functions</script>
               </div>';
$(testdiv).appendTo(document.body);
```

After running above code, div that is added is missing javascript, i.e everything inside < script type="text/javascript" >

Is this known issue with appendTo ?

Comment: so the only thing added is '<div id="Hello"></div>'?

Comment: Nope. It adds <div id="hello"><p>hiii</p></div>

Answer (score 2):

You might need to chop up the `<script>` tags.
This works:

```
var testdiv = '<div id="hello"><p>hiii</p><scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript">console.log("buu")</scr'+'ipt></div>';
$(testdiv).appendTo(document.body);
```

Comment: I am not sure I can do that.. since I have entire content.

Answer (score 0):

```
var testdiv = '<div id="hello"><p>hiii</p><script type="text/javascript">alert(\'foo\')</script></div>';
$(testdiv).appendTo(document.body);
```

I replaced "some javascript" with an alert, and it works fine for me.
Note that I had to escape the quotes I was using in the string, that may have been it.

I agree with jonscottclark about getScript(). There are indeed much better ways to include and execute additional scripts.